# Manejo de archivos csv en Node js

Tags: nodejs, async-await

Hola amigos soy nuevo en nodeJS y estoy aprendiendo sobre el manejo de archivos csv, he usado la libreria 'csvtojson' para el manejo pero trabaja con funciones async/await, mi pregunta es ¿Puedo Guardar el resultado de esta funcion async dentro de una variable let,var,const? o ¿tengo que cambiar de estructura de mi codigo?
mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
//el codigo
const CSVtoJSON = require('csvtojson');

let load_data = async() => {
      let csv = await (CSVtoJSON().fromFile('./data1.csv'));
      return csv;
}

//opciones que use para obtener el resultado pero no funcionan
var data = load_data();
var data = load_data().then(resp => { return resp; });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toda función tipo [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) devuelve una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

Por lo tanto para capturar el resultado (Promesa resuelta) o el error (Promesa rechazada), debes usar los métodos `then()` y `catch()` de la misma.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let data = load_data();
// Ahora data es una Promesa.
data
 .then( resultado => {
   // ahora sí el resultado está disponible para trabajar con el mismo
   console.log(resultado);
 })
 .catch( error => {
   // si la Promesa es rechazada, aquí capturamos el error
   console.error(error.message);
 });
```

Ahora, si lo que necesitas es disponer del resultado de tu Promesa *inmediatamente* después de llamar a ejecución a tu función, debes envolver tu código dentro de otra función `async` para poder usar `await` y recibir el resultado en una variable.

Por ejemplo:

```js
//dentro de una función tipo async:
const miMetodoAsync = async () => {
  // cuando se trabaja con Promesas usando `await`
  // se debe usar un bloque try catch
  try {
    let resultado = await load_data();
    // ahora resultado tiene el valor de la Promesa resuelta
    console.log(resultado);
  } catch (error) {
    // aqui capturamos cuando la Promesa es rechazada
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

Como puedes observar en ambos casos, nunca tendrás disponible directamente el resultado de la ejecución asíncrona en una variable global inmediatamente en tu código.

Otra recomendación que puede hacerte ya que comienzas a trabajar con Node, no uses o declares variables con `var`. Usa siempre `let` y `const`.